# How to call web api with multiple parameter in c# xamarin forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I know this is a repeated question. I have tried many examples showed on stackoverflow. But the API is still not calling and it shows 404 not found error. I have tried the below examples,

**Example 1:**

```
using (var loginData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    loginData.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login.Email)), "emailId");
    loginData.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Password)), "password");
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://6cxsfera.ngrok.io/api/users/authenticate", loginData);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
JObject loginData = new JObject();
loginData.Add("emailId", login.Email);
loginData.Add("password", this.Password);
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpContent = new StringContent(loginData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://6cxsfera.ngrok.io/api/users/authenticate", httpContent);
```

**My API:**

```
[Route("authenticate")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(HttpRequestMessage request, string emailId, string password)
{
}
```

Please suggest me to pass multiple parameters to web API in c# xamarin forms.

Comment: are u able to call it with postman?

Comment: @VatanSoni, I have called my API using postman, it's working fine. But when I call it from xamarin forms viewmodel, it shows 404 not found error.

Comment: You can generate code by postman. Then check hat you are missing. you can even use same code generated by postman. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/

Comment: just install restSharp nuget package.. it will work with postman generated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate code by postman. Then check hat you are missing. you can even use same code generated by postman. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/

just install restSharp nuget package.. it will work with postman generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating JObject create a class which holds your emailId and password property like below.

```
public class UserModel
{
   public string emailId {get;set;}
   public string password {get;set;}
}
```

now later instantiate UserModel and assign values like below

```
UserModel user = new UserModel
{
   emailId = "emailId",
   password = "password"
};
```

Serialize UserModel like below

```
string serializedModel = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
var contents = new StringContent(serializedModel);
contents.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
```

Make a Post Request

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://6cxsfera.ngrok.io/api/users/authenticate", contents);
```

If the above solution doesn't work try changing your Web Api method route like below

```
Route["api/users/authenticate"]
```

Hope this will solve your issue... :)

Comment: my requirement is to send multiple parameters on web API in xamarin forms. In my model class, there is no password property.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
{
   var formcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("emailId",emailId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password","password")
    });

  var request = await httpclient .PostAsync("http://6cxsfera.ngrok.io/api/users/authenticate", formcontent);
  request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Zhu-MSFT, 404 not found exception is occurring.

Comment: Zhu, I have used like this, `var uri = new UriBuilder($"http://6cxsfera.ngrok.io/api/users/authenticate?emailid={emailId}&password={password}"); var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), null);`